# Moving entries from one Google Keep list to another

Tags: google-keep

Say I have two lists in Google Keep.  Is there a clean way to move an entry from one list to another?  If neither list is "opened" I can't even select an entry from either one, and if one list is "opened" the other one is inaccessible, so I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way is to open one note, copy all its content, then paste it into the other note.

You could open two browser windows side-by-side with the source note in one and the target in the other to make it easier.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is correct:

1. Open the first note.
2. Select the desired lines, Copy.
3. Open the second note.
4. Select the insertion point, Paste.

As this [Google Support thread](https://support.google.com/assistant/thread/489316) indicates, dragging between Keep lists is not supported, and Google has no plans to add that feature.

BTW, Google **Tasks** supports inter-list dragging.

BTW 2, if you need to copy multiple checklist items in Keep, click the dots menu, Hide  Checkboxes. Copy as plain text, then revert to Show Checkboxes.